# precision in variables

Tags: c#, variables, double

I have problems with the precision of the variables when performing calculations and comparing the results. I am working in C #. Here is an example.

```cs
double ImporteDebe;
ImporteDebe = 0;
double base1;
base1 = Convert.ToDouble("10,22");
double PorcentajeIva1;
PorcentajeIva1 = Convert.ToDouble("0,21");
double Iva1;
Iva1 = Convert.ToDouble((base1 * PorcentajeIva1).ToString("N2")); //2,1462 -> 2,15

ImporteDebe = ImporteDebe + base1; // 10,22
ImporteDebe = ImporteDebe + Iva1;// 10,22 + 2,15 = 12,37000000001

if (ImporteDebe == (base1 + Iva1))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(Convert.ToString(ImporteDebe));//condition is never met
}
```

if you run the code you see that the condition "ImporteDebe == (base1 + Iva1)" is never met

Does the problem have a simple solution?

Comment: Works fine for me; are you sure?

Comment: [works for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S2gmEW).

Comment: Try using decimal if double is not specifically required.

Comment: I'm working with Visual Studio 17 and C#. It does not work for me. Condition "ImporteDebe==base1+Iva1" is never satisfied.

Comment: With decimal variables works fine. Use decimal instead of double which implies in relation to executable? Size or speed of execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not compare doubles using the  `== operator`

but instead like in the official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?view=net-5.0):

```
// Initialize two doubles with apparently identical values
double double1 = .333333;
double double2 = (double) 1/3;
// Define the tolerance for variation in their values
double difference = Math.Abs(double1 * .00001);

// Compare the values
// The output to the console indicates that the two values are equal
if (Math.Abs(double1 - double2) <= difference)
   Console.WriteLine("double1 and double2 are equal.");
else
   Console.WriteLine("double1 and double2 are unequal.");
```

Comment: Very good advise in general, but the code in the question should still work as the values on both sides are calculated bit as `10.22 + 2.15`

Comment: But they **might** end up slightly different based on the CPU or the compiler used or even the build configuration. This answer is correct